# HTML css margin pading content border

Tags: html, css

What is my problem? I cannot find a solution to make it look like this 
[Hello World box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFlBI.jpg) I'm not very good at coding but I'm trying to understand what I did wrong. Can someone help me please and fix my code?

```css
.mano-modelis .content {
  content: "Hello World!";
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

.mano-modelis .padding {
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}

.mano-modelis .border {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.mano-modelis .margin {
  background: blue;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px;
  transition: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="mano-modelis">
  <div class="margin">
    <div class="border">
      <div class="padding">
        <div class="content">Hello world!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you attempted to link to a reference image but were unsuccessful, please describe the layout you're attempting to achieve or please try including your reference image again.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using so many elements and repeating property declarations in your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simplified version of linked image, I used only two elements.

```css
.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.green {
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  height: 250px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  line-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
  <div class="green">
    Hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

it can also be done with one element, like this:

```css
.green {
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  box-sizing: boreder-box;
  line-height: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px blue;
}
```

```html
  <div class="green">
    Hello world
  </div>
```

And here is it with your code, fixed:

```css
.mano-modelis .margin {
  background: blue;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.mano-modelis .content {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 270px;
  background-color: green;
}

.mano-modelis .padding {
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="mano-modelis">
  <div class="margin">
    <div class="border">
      <div class="padding">
        <div class="content">Hello world!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from an outer DIV having padding and an inner DIV sharing the same width with an inner DIV. The inner DIV will start inside the padding and therefor overflows the outer DIV.

Here's a couple simplified solutions if you don't need all those extra elements.

#### One Element Using `outline` for Outer Border

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.mano-modelis {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 15px; /* provides buffer for outline below as outlines don't take up space. */
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  outline: 15px solid blue;
  border: 15px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="mano-modelis">Hello world!</div>
```

#### One Element Using `::before` Pseudo Element for Outer Border

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.mano-modelis {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 15px; /* Buffer space for pseudo element */
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
  border: 15px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}

.mano-modelis::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  right: -30px;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: -30px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="mano-modelis">Hello world!</div>
```

There's additional solutions out there that I'm sure others will cover.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're aiming to get something like this...

```css
.margin,
.border,
.padding,
.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.margin {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}

.border {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.padding {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="mano-modelis">
  <div class="margin">
    <div class="border">
      <div class="padding">
        <div class="content">Hello world!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```